# nginx configuration for socket.io/websockets

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io

I'm having some trouble configuring nginx to proxy websockets. I have a node.js app that uses socket.io v0.9.16 listening for connections on port 9090 and nginx v1.6.2 listening on port 9000, and (supposedly) configured to proxy requests on to my node.js app. nginx config is shown below:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 9000;
    server_name mysite.com;
    location / {
            root /var/www/mysite/web;
    }
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is with nginx, because if I access my node app directly on port 9090 then both the static content in `/var/www/mysite/web` and the websockets work fine, but if I try to go via nginx on port 9000 then only the static content is served correctly.

Chrome dev tools shows that the initial request to socket.io (http://my.ip.add.ress:9000/socket.io/1/?t=1414606847141) gets 'cancelled' by the browser (I've tried on Firefox and Safari with similar results).

Could this be a security issue? Does the browser somehow 'know' that socket.io is running on port 9090 and refuses to connect to it via 9000? I'm pretty stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this fixed. The problem was that in my client-side code I was connecting to the server using an IP address rather than a hostname:

```
io.connect('http://my.ip.add.ress')
```

so the socket.io requests weren't being matched by the nginx config, changing the above line to use the 'mysite.com' hostname solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using websockets/socket.io, You should use ip_hash.

`upstream project {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.2:4000;
    server 127.0.0.3:4000;
}`

Comment: does ip_hash give any benefit if you aren't load balancing? I only have my app running on 1 server

Comment: Yes, clients may connect on different server and whenever one server goes down, you get handsaked to next server without loading static contents.